# Searching for a Greek letter in a string Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out a way to search for a Greek letter in a string replace it with another character. For example

```
value = "Hello μ!";
value.replace("μ", "You");
alert(value);

//Alerted value should be "Hello You!"
```

Unfortunately this isn't working.  I tried searching for answers online but to no avail.  Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You have to reassign the value. The replace function does not modify the existing value because strings are immutable in Javascript. This works:

`value = value.replace("μ", "You")`

```js
value = "Hello μ!";
value = value.replace("μ", "You");
alert(value);
```

Comment: Okay I was dumb to forget the reassignment in this example. However, what you provided me unfortunately still doesn't work.  It's seemingly ignoring the fact that the greek letter is in the string.

Comment: I guess it has to be something with my code because I'm passing this value into a function and when I'm trying to replace the string with the new characters it's seemingly getting ignored.